# how can i call GWT method from swing application

Tags: java, swing, gwt

Iam very beginner in gwt, i have a requirement to initailse  gwt class or call gwt method from swing class. is it possible to do it?
otherwise is there any process to do such things?

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe with RequestFactory. You can access to RequestFactories with Andorid, so I guess it should also be possible with other Java Applications.

Comment: Are you directly using the GWT code in your java app, or are you trying to access functions on your GWT website remotely?

Comment: Sorry for the late response as i posted it late night, I have to called GWT methods in swing app...

Answer (score 2):

GWT code is translated into JavaScript and runs inside the user's browser. It has absolutely no way of accessing code or functions in the user's machine other than what the browsers allow (like cookies). Swing is a completely different framework for desktop applications (although it certainly inspired the design of GWT), so the two frameworks are not intended to work together.